# Excel VBA: Save active worksheet as PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using some code to save an active worksheet to PDF, using the current date/time as the filename, and saving into a SharePoint folder.

```
Sub Save()

Dim strFilename     As String

strFilename = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm")

Sheets("Weather Warning Action Sheet").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/xxx/Paperwork and Admin/WX Warnings/2020/" & strFilename & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

This code has been working fine for a while, but has suddenly come up with the "Run-time error '1004': Document not saved" error message.

Debugging shows this as the error:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/xxx/Paperwork and Admin/WX Warnings/2020/" & strFilename & ".pdf" _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciate.

Many thanks,

James

Comment: Check the file name it contains white areas

Comment: @MoKhalefa I've tried adding %20 instead of the blank spaces but still get the same error message.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563933/error-run-time-error-1004-document-not-saved

Comment: Try it without seperating the parameters by commas.