# How to Create PDF in Excel and Immediately Send as Email

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet which is calculating the Performance Indicators of the Employees. I want to send their performance indicators via email. I am trying to use the following code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub create_and_email_pdf()
    Dim EmailSubject As String, EmailSignature As String
    Dim CurrentMonth As String, DestFolder As String, PDFFile As String
    Dim Email_To As String, Email_CC As String, Email_BCC As String
    Dim OpenPDFAfterCreating As Boolean, AlwaysOverwritePDF As Boolean, DisplayEmail As Boolean
    Dim OverwritePDF As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim OutlookApp As Object, OutlookMail As Object
    CurrentMonth = ""
    
        EmailSubject = "Invoice Attached for "
        OpenPDFAfterCreating = False
        AlwaysOverwritePDF = False
        DisplayEmail = True
        Email_To = ""
        Email_CC = ""
        Email_BCC = ""
               
    ' ******************************************************
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            
            If .Show = True Then
                DestFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
              
            Else
            
                MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
                    
                Exit Sub
                
            End If
            
        End With
        
        CurrentMonth = Mid(ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Value, InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Range("G2").Value, " ") + 1)
        
        PDFFile = DestFolder & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveSheet.Name _
                    & "_" & CurrentMonth & ".pdf"
       
        If Len(Dir(PDFFile)) > 0 Then
        
            If AlwaysOverwritePDF = False Then
            
                OverwritePDF = MsgBox(PDFFile & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
            
                On Error Resume Next
               
                If OverwritePDF = vbYes Then
        
                    Kill PDFFile
            
                Else
        
                    MsgBox "OK then, if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
                    
                    Exit Sub
            
                End If
    
            Else
            
                On Error Resume Next
                Kill PDFFile
                
            End If
            
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            
                MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
                    
                Exit Sub
            
            End If
                
        End If
       
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
            :=False
    
        'Create an Outlook object and new mail message
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
            
        'Display email and specify To, Subject, etc
        With OutlookMail
            
            .Display
            .To = Email_To
            .CC = Email_CC
            .BCC = Email_BCC
            .Subject = EmailSubject & CurrentMonth
            .Attachments.Add PDFFile
                    
            If DisplayEmail = False Then
                .Send
            End If
            
        End With
     
End Sub
```

When I try to run this code, it gives me the following error:
[image]

On debugging the code it shows me the following highlighted line.
[image]

Comment: What is the value of G2. See [error-1004-document-not-saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563933/error-run-time-error-1004-document-not-saved)

Answer (score 0):

Check the pdffile variable has valid path value, I can see you are generating the pdfile path.